# DOM location of ItemView when passed in CompositeView - Marionette

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom, marionette

I have an `ItemView` like this:

```
var Userview= Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#user1",
        el: "#imp1"    
});
```

**Question**: Does this mean that template of ItemView: `#user1` will go into the (say) div with `id=imp1` in the DOM, when rendered?

(If not, then I guess I can use regions to render Userview in a certain div in the DOM, so its fine!)

Now, in case of rendering a `CompositeView`, I use `Region1.show()` for `CompositeView`. In this case, how can I render a (childView) `ItemView` of the `CompositeView` at a specific location (say a div with an id) in the DOM. 
 
(As I am calling `Region1.show()` on the `CompositeView` and not on the `ItemView`, I dont know how to render the `ItemView` at a specific location on the DOM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the trick is to define a `childViewContainer: "#some_id"` inside the `CompositeView` definition. It will define location of the (childView) `itemView`.
 
Also, using the word `itemView` inside `CompositeView` will cause an error, we need to use 
`childView: child_view_name`

Answer (score 1):

If the ItemView is the CompositeView child, then you **cannot** render that at a specific location in the **DOM**.
You can only render on a specific location **inside** the CompositeView(childViewContainer), and the CompositeView will render directly into DOM via a region.

So, if you want to render an ItemView at a specific location in the DOM, you should use only a Region and the ItemView, without compositeView.

```
var myView = new MyView();
myRegion.show(myView);
```